# How to convert a sequence of characters into a date format to store in the database?

Tags: java, string, oracle, date, numbers

Based on the filename i have to break down the string into a different array of elements and i was able to extract the timestamp from the file naming convention and now i need to pass this string to a date format to be stored into the db tables:

Example:
`20200913204839` string  needs to be converted into date format as `13-sep-2020 20:48:39` (column_name) and the pl/sql block has the parameter value in this format column name-datatype (varchar2) -and value inside the insert statement as :

```
to_date(column_name,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

This is the equivalent matlab code:

```
 fn.fntestdate = datestr(datenum(column_name,'yymmddHHMM'),'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

How do i incorporate the same logic in **Java**?

I tried several functions  **SimpleDateFormat** trying to parse it,but was receiving "unparseable funcction" ERROR.

I think column_name has to be converted into number and then converted to date before parsing it?
Requires several multiple implicit conversions before loading. Suggest the best possible approach for this

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` andother classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What did your search bring up? Similar questions have been asked and answered over and over. Only as I tried to say already, ignore the answers showing the use of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I further recommend that you don’t store your date as `varchar2` in the database but use its `datetime` or even better `timestamp with time zone` datatype. Then also don’t send the date as a string to the database but send a `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` (the classes mentioned are from java.time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that works with your test cases:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
public class StringToDateExample1 {  
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {  
        String sDate1="20200913204839";  
        Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").parse(sDate1);  
        System.out.println(date1);
    }  
}
```

With test case `20200913204839` it returns:

```
Sun Sep 13 20:48:39 UTC 2020
```

Here's what the characters in the SimpleDateFormat mean:

`yyyy` signifies a year (Example: 2020)

`MM` signifies a month (Example: July, August)

`dd` signifies a day in a month (Example: 15)

`HH` signifies an hour in a day (Example: 20)

`mm` and `ss` signify minutes and seconds respectively (Example: 52:34)

It doesn't have to be a Date - just a String works fine.

And yes - using SimpleDateFormat works just fine.

**EDIT: Specific Formatting**

I've formatted it specifically for your case:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
public class StringToDateExample1 {  
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {  
        String sDate1="20200913204839";  
        Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").parse(sDate1);
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-EE-yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(date1);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }  
}
```

We first parse the String into a date, from which we can format.

A test case `20200913204839` returns:

```
13-Sun-2020 08:48:39
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution,i got just the same but before loading into the oracle database i need to have the date in this format :'12-sep-2020 5:00:45'   'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MM:SS' which is  a string(varchar2) column in db,please suggest the final step?

Comment: I just made some tweaks to it and i got the output as desired,you're awesome thanks Aniox  ,keep it up :) This was the final code i had compiled
{  
       String sDate1="20200913204839";  
     Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").parse(sDate1);  
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date1);
        System.out.println(formatted);
  }

Comment: Ah yes, EE can be replaced with MMM. Cheers!

Comment: Caution: a SimpleDateFormat uses the system’s default timezone, unless its timezone is explicitly set.  This may or may not be desired behavior.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: This is wrong: *`hh` signifies an hour in a day (Example: 20)*. Lower case `hh` is for hour with AM or PM from 01 through 12.

Comment: @OleV.V. You are very right. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> … Suggest the best possible approach for this

This is exactly what I am doing. :-)

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

`13-sep-2020 20:48:39` is a nice date and time of day. I suppose that you meant it to indicate a point in time. It only makes sense as such within a time zone. So to store a point in time store the time with a time zone (such as Asia/Ust-Nera) or an offset from UTC (such as +10:00). Since you are using an Oracle database: If I have been correctly informed, the `timestamp with time zone` datatype of Oracle (contrary to other RDBMSs) is what it says: a timestamp with a time zone. So you should be able to transfer a Java `ZonedDateTime` to it. Do that.

First, to parse the string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    
    String dateTimeFromFileName = "20200913204839";
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeFromFileName, formatter)
            .atZone(zone);
    System.out.println("Parsed date-time: " + dateTime);
```

Output so far is in my time zone:

> Parsed date-time: 2020-09-13T20:48:39+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

I have used the default time zone of my JVM. If you can, specify a time zone in the *region/city* format, for example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Ust-Nera");
```

Second, to pass to a PL/SQL block that expects `timestamp with time zone` (not tested since I haven’t got an Oracle database at hand):

```
    CallableStatement stmt = yourDatabaseConnection
            .prepareCall("/* Your PL/SQL call goes here */");
    stmt.setObject(1, dateTime);
    stmt.execute();
```

### To sum up the recommendations

- Don’t store nor handle your date as `varchar2` in the database but use its `datetime` or even better `timestamp with time zone` datatype.
- Don’t send the date as a string to the database. Since JDBC 4.2, send an appropriate type from `java.time`. The documentation of your JDBC driver should tell you the correct Java type to use.
- In Java always use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, for you date and time work.

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Very well organized explanation! Every point in the summary section has been properly explained in the preceding paragraphs.