# SimpleDateFormat Japanese time

Tags: java, time, locale, simpledateformat, cjk

The time I have is -> September 15 2020 11:10:25

I am using this code to format it in Japanese

```
 timeFormatStr = "YYYY MMMMMMMMMM DD HH:mm:ss z"; 
 SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormatStr, locale);
 timeStr = sdf.format(new Date(time));
```

The timeStr looks like this (does not look right).

2020 9月 259 23:10:25 UTC

Any idea what the format string should be? I checked that the locale is - ja_JP.eucjp

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911330/how-to-convert-a-sequence-of-characters-into-a-date-format-to-store-in-the-datab/63911886#63911886) might be helpful

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Not knowing Japanese, could you tell us your expected result and point out precisely in what way the string that you got doesn’t look right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`YYYY MMMMMMMMMM DD HH:mm:ss z` is not how the Japanese format their dates and times. You should use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), and call `ofLocalizedDateTime` and `withLocale`. This will produce a formatter that produces strings in a native Japanese format.

```
String formatted = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL) // choose a style here
        .withLocale(Locale.JAPANESE)
        .format(new Date(time).toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // choose a timezone here
System.out.println(formatted); // 1970年1月1日木曜日 0時00分00秒 Z
```

You shouldn't really be using `Date`s anymore. You should instead give the `DateTimeFormatter` a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) directly.

Comment: With this code, the time string is -> 16 9月 2020 11:02:05

I wanted the time in YYYY MMMMMMM DD format.

Comment: @Tas but that’s not how the Japanese format their dates. They go yyyy年MM月dd日. [My code will produce an output like the one shown in the comment.](https://ideone.com/WJYkbj)

Comment: @Tas I’m sorry, it still isn’t clear to me. Could you give us **an example** of how you believe that YYYY MMMMMMM DD should look like? Asking because I understand that you are neither satisfied with how it looks in your question nor in this answer, but I don’t yet understand what’s wrong with either of them.